# Wordpress - How to delete unused media (whole website)

Tags: wordpress

I need to clean my database (Mysql) of my Wordpress (latest version).
So i want to clean up the media table, but I need to, first of, find out what entries to delete.

I found some queries that find unattached media, but, sometimes, my medias aren't `attached`. I mean, sometimes, I upload my media, get the link, and paste it in an article ...

Do you think it's possible to make a SQL query who takes this into account?

Comment: use media cleaner plugin

Comment: Yes, but it's just checking the attached media, no?

Comment: Yes. It will check attached media

Comment: Ok, I don't think it's enough ... What about file not "attached" but just pasted into the page content?

Answer (score 0):

`wp-content->uploads` folder wich is where all the files are..

> I found some queries that find unattached media, but, sometimes, my
>   medias aren't attached. I mean, sometimes, I upload my media, get the
>   link, and paste it in an article ..

Those uploads that are not `"attached"` are not in the databse. the link that is given to you is a simple path and URL.

All the attachments are saved to `wp-content->uploads` folder unless it was changed by a plugin or a `wp-config` constant

To delete only unused attachments or media you will need to either compare all the results of a scan of all your `wp-content->upload` folder with all the `content` and `excerpt` and possibly `meta` ( depending on theme and plugins ) of all your posts..

To do exactly what you ask can be a bit tricky without knowing all the details of the structure of the site because any theme or plugin can use an uploaded image in a different way ( DB-wise).

You can find some suggested solutions here :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149156/how-do-i-delete-all-unused-images-from-my-uploads-directory

But like I said - depending on the structure of your theme / plugins / website - none of them can be 100% sure solution. No plugin can guess that.

If you are referring only to media inside `posts` then those solutions can work..

Comment: Thank you. It's gonna be a huge task haha. Maybe, for each file like /wp-content/upload/XX/XX/XX.jpg I have to search for `XX/XX/XX.jpg` across all my database ...

Comment: yes. basically yes. you can also do it manually via the media upload interface if you remember what is used and what is not. again - I do not know your site structure and size.

Comment: More than 50K medias, I won't do it one by one haha

Comment: No. I guess not. Then if I were you I would just write a small plugin myself to scan the content folder and then search for strings. should not be too complicated.. and you cn also try the plugins suggested in other comments and then modify them  to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just log in to wordpress.com and select any site you want to delete. After select side, in left side menu go **to settings > general.**

After selecting general tab go last in that page you will see option *DELETE YOUR SITE PERMANENTLY*.

[image: DELETE YOUR SITE PERMANENTLY]

After that again select *DELETE SITE* and enter site name you want to delete and its done.